# Let start work on LaTeX and forget the MS Office

Tags: discussion

When I start working on LaTeX during my Master Thesis, I enjoy alot. After that I start working on LaTeX regularly and working on different LaTeX templates like CV, Cover Letters etc. Now I am totally depend on LaTeX. So tell me, Now I forget the MS Office and continue working on LaTeX.

Comment: Ehm, good for you? I don't really understand what you're trying to say here. Are you asking whether you should drop MS Office altogether?

Comment: Please remember that the name "meta" of this Meta site doesn't mean we shall ask meta questions (= soft questions) here. It means that we can ask/discuss topics about the main site here.

Comment: I don't see a question in there. Is it supposed to be *How I forget?*

Answer (score 9):

You can remove it via Control Panel --> Programs and Features